# SQL Server 2012 - Convert a From-To columned table into a numbered sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to write a SQL query in SQL Server 2012 to convert a table that has 2 columns `FROM` and `TO` into a table that has a numerical sequence of the described route taken if you logically follow the from-to direction. I have been struggling for hours on this and any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

EXAMPLE:

[image]

Comment: How is the input table sorted? SQL tables have no order without an explicit `ORDER BY`

Comment: I don't think there is a hard coded and/or reliable sort order for the input table.  I assumed you could sort the Input table by either column in the solution itself, if warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this I'll have to assume either a sort order or a "base record". I.e. I need to know which record should be the starting point. In this example I have simply hardcoded the value of the base record.

```
WITH RecursiveCTE AS(
    SELECT 
        [FROM], [TO],
        1 AS SequenceNo
    FROM InputTable
    WHERE [FROM] = 'B' --Hardcoded value to select a base record
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        t.[FROM], t.[TO],
        SequenceNo + 1 AS SequenceNo
    FROM RecursiveCTE e
        INNER JOIN InputTable t ON e.[TO] = t.[FROM]
)
--Get all records except the last one via the Recursive CTE
SELECT 
    [FROM] AS [Node],
    SequenceNo
FROM RecursiveCTE
UNION ALL
--Get the last record in a separate query
SELECT TOP 1
    [TO] AS [Node],
    SequenceNo + 1 AS SequenceNo
FROM RecursiveCTE
WHERE SequenceNo = (SELECT MAX(SequenceNo) FROM RecursiveCTE)
```

The query uses a recursive CTE to get all records except the last one. The last record is added by the UNION ALL statement at the end.

Comment: Thank you. Using a variant of this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no cycles, you can use a recursive cte:

```
with cte as (
      select e.from, e.to, 1 as lev
      from example e
      where not exists (select 1 from example e2 where e2.to = e.from) 
      union all
      select e.from, e.to, cte.lev + 1
      from cte join
           example e
           on cte.to = e.from
    )
select e.from, lev
from cte;
```

Comment: This doesn't get the final level.  It only gets down to `E - 4`.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you have random data on [from] or [to] column - (may be there more data in [from] column not in [to] column and vise-versa, so

**if there is no problem with making an order using [from] and [to] column use the below query**

```
with dataTest as
(
 select [From], [to] , ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [From], [to]) lvl from InputTable e
)
 ,dataD as
 (
   select [From] node,(lvl*2)-1 lvl from dataTest
   union all
   select [To] node,(lvl*2) lvl from dataTest
 )
 ,lastD as
 (
  select  node, lvl, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by node order by lvl) rn from dataD 
 )
 select node, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by lvl) squence  from lastD where rn=1 order by lvl
```

**if your data is typically as you set in the sample you can use**

```
with dataTest as
(
 select [From], [to] ,1 lvl from InputTable e
 where not exists (select 1 from InputTable e2 where e2.[to] = e.[from]) 
 union all
  select e.[from], e.[to], dataTest.lvl + 1
  from dataTest join
  InputTable e  on dataTest.[to] = e.[from]
)
,dataD as
(
 select [From] node,(lvl*2)-1 lvl from dataTest
 union all
 select [To] node,(lvl*2) lvl from dataTest
)
,lastD as
 (
  select  node, lvl, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by node order by lvl) rn    
  from dataD 
 )
  select node, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by lvl) squence  from lastD where rn=1 order by lvl
```

**Hope these help you or give you an idea.**

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort.  I think the simpler CTE with a 'last row union' does the trick